# Amazon Redshift rank group

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dense-rank

I'm trying to do a ranking on the 1st 10, and then group the remaining in groups of 1000 (based on volume)

Below is the desired results, whats the easiest way to do this?

desired results

[image: desired results]

I can get the ranking on volume all the way down using the following, but would like to group anything more than a ranking of 10

```
DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY count (DISTINCT volume_key)  DESC)as rnk_loc_Vol
```

Comment: See if NTILE() is available and/or consider a case expression where after the first 10 you use arithmetic on the volume, perhaps a division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to rank with regular function first (raw rank), then get tenth record's volume next to every row and produce another column (final rank) which is 1 to 10 or 11+integer division of the delta between tenth record volume and row's volume by 1000.

```
with 
ranked_entries as (
    select *
    ,dense_rank() over (partition by date order by volume desc) as raw_rnk
    from tbl
)
,tenth_entry as (
    select *
    ,min(case when raw_rnk<11 then volume end) over (partition by date) as tenth_record_volume
    from tbl
)
select *
,case 
    when raw_rnk<11 then raw_rnk 
    else 11+(tenth_record_volume-volume)/1000 
 end as final_rnk
from tenth_entry
```

(haven't tested though)

Comment: i wondered about this method - but it depends having some rows with values in each 10k range. but some will be empty. imagine a really high value.

Comment: @JonScott this is fixable - you can add 2 additional layers, one with `LAG` against the final rank to show the previous row's rank, and the final layer with correct rank would be the running sum of rows where rank is not equal to previous rank, like `1+sum(case when final_rnk!=prev_final_rnk then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date order by volume,rank)`

Comment: thanks @AlexYes, that actually worked.

For anyone else that needs to use this, you can play around with the top (n) raw rank, and change the grouping volume from 1000 to meet your needs

Comment: @JonScott, no empty/ nulls were bought back, i was getting nulls in old methods where i was using a case statement

Comment: @AlexYes sorry, im new to stackoverflow, was looking for it, found it now, thanks again